# Searching on Taxonomy terms with the Search API module?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, search

I've been playing around with the Search API module for a little bit now, and it seems to be working fairly well, but I can't figure out how or why I am not able to search on terms even though they are selected among the search fields.

Does anyone have any hints or pointers on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only search on full text fields, so you need to not only add the term but also fx make the term name searchable, another option is to use terms as facets, but then you can't search on them using full text.

Comment: How do you mean by "so you need to not only add the term but also fx make the term name searchable"? Under `Add related fields` I have also added my `Taxonomy >> Name` as a `Fulltext` field

Comment: Then that should work. You might need to tweak weights to see the effect though.

Comment: Not entirely sure what happened, but I uninstalled and reinstalled the `entity` and `search_api` modules and did everything the same way as before, only difference is that now it's working :P

Answer (score 5):

On the field index page, at the bottom see **Add related fields** select the term field you want to search. When you save, this adds a number of items associated with the term fields. Then select **Taxonomy >> Name** to index as Fulltext. Now it is searchable.