# Search a product - Search API Module

Tags: 7, commerce, search, views

I'm creating a e-commerce website, with a type of content "Products". I'm using Search API to be able to have Facets filters on my views. I linked the type of content "Products" to the search API. So i have different facets filers available. Everything is working perfectly.

Now I would to be able to search a product. On my search results page i can have my facets filters.

So I tried 2 options :

1) I found [this](http://www.webwash.net/tutorials/intro-search-api-part-1-how-create-search-pages) tutorial and I tried but it didn't work

2) I tried the [Search API Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_page) module
and I have the same problem, nothing is working. When I search something, it found nothing. I tried to find out some tutorials to see if I miss something.

I tried to find out some tutorials about how to use Search API Pages module, but I found nothing useful.

I found [this previous post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10465/searching-on-taxonomy-terms-with-the-search-api-module) which is similar as my problem :

But that doesn't help me either

Does anyone have an idea ?

Edit : I'm not using Apache Solr on my server

Comment: I solved my problem.

Well i don't if what i did was the issue but it's working so ^^

I went in the parameters of the Search API Module. I went on the tab "Filters", in the "Precesseurs" part i just activated this 2 things :

HTML filter
Tokenizer

I re-indexed everything and by magic it's working.

Comment: Well. it's glad you've solved your problem. But please remember that this site is for Q+A, not a forum I'm afraid. You can post your solution as answer, instead of updating your post as [PROBLEM SOLVED], Please read [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help)and [Tour](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Hello,

Ok i'm sorry about that, i just put my comment as an answer. 

But i'm new on this website, i have to wait 2 days before accept my own answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

Well i don't if what i did was the issue but it's working so ^^

I went in the parameters of the Search API Module. I went on the tab "Filters", in the "Precesseurs" part i just activated this 2 things : HTML filter Tokenizer I re-indexed everything and by magic it's working.