# Search_api not searching taxonomy names

Tags: views, 8, search

I feel like I have tried messing with every setting I can find but I simple cannot make my search_api search view return any results based on taxonomy names.

I want to be able to search based on a custom taxonomy and search on the fulltext field of the name.

- I am using the built in database.
- I have added the taxonomy term database sources.
- I have added a relationship for the taxonomy term on
  my custom views
- In the fulltext search on the view the taxonomy name field is selected to be searched
- In the index I have added the custom taxonomy I want included.
- I have set it to fulltext and boosted in to 5.0

What else am I suppose to do?

Does anyone know of any guide or any information that explains how to make this work? It has been a month I still cannot get this module to return content that has associated taxonomy terms.

Is there any modules that do this? It should be a standard use case...

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same case, reinstall the search and entity modules. And try to install search_api using Database Search Default module and after installation, uninstall the database search Default module. Boost taxonomy name to 8 or 13. Then it should work.

Comment: Reference link : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10465/searching-on-taxonomy-terms-with-the-search-api-module

Comment: This didn't appear to work.